# MongoMapper Parent Inheritance

Tags: mongomapper

I am trying to get a better and organized result from using class inheritance with MongoMapper, but having some trouble.

```
class Item
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
end

class Picture < Item
  key :url, String
end

class Video < Item
  key :length, Integer
end
```

When I run the following commands, they don't quite return what I am expecting.

```
>> Item.all
=> [#<Item name: "Testing", created_at: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 20:02:48 PST -08:00, updated_at: Mon, 04 Jan 2010 13:01:31 PST -08:00, _id: 4b416868010e2a04d0000002, views: 0, user_id: 4b416844010e2a04d0000001, description: "lorem?">]
>> Video.all
=> [#<Video name: "Testing", created_at: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 20:02:48 PST -08:00, updated_at: Mon, 04 Jan 2010 13:01:31 PST -08:00, _id: 4b416868010e2a04d0000002, views: 0, user_id: 4b416844010e2a04d0000001, description: "lorem?">]
>> Picture.all
=> [#<Picture name: "Testing", created_at: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 20:02:48 PST -08:00, updated_at: Mon, 04 Jan 2010 13:01:31 PST -08:00, _id: 4b416868010e2a04d0000002, views: 0, user_id: 4b416844010e2a04d0000001, description: "lorem?">]
```

They are all the same result, I would expect to have `Item.all` list all of the results, so including itself, `Picture`, and `Video`. But if the item is actually a `Picture`, I would like it to be returned if I ran `Picture.all` and not if I run `Video.all`. Do you see what I mean?

Am I misunderstanding how the inheritance works here? If I am what is the best way to replicate this sort of behavior? I am trying to follow [this](http://railstips.org/2009/12/18/why-i-think-mongo-is-to-databases-what-rails-was-to-frameworks) (point 2) as a guideline of how I want this work. I assume he can run `Link.all` to find all the links, and not include every other class that inherits from `Item`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example you link to is a little misleading (or maybe just hard to follow) in that it doesn't show the full definition for the `Item` model. In order to use inheritance in your models, you'll need to define a key `_type` on the parent model. MongoMapper will then automatically set that key to the class name of the actual class of that document. So, for instance, you models would now look like this:

```
class Item
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :_type, String
end

class Picture < Item
  key :url, String
end

class Video < Item
  key :length, Integer
end
```

and the output of your searches (assuming you created a `Picture` object) will turn into:

```
>> Item.all
=> [#<Picture name: "Testing", _type: "Picture", created_at: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 20:02:48 PST -08:00, updated_at: Mon, 04 Jan 2010 13:01:31 PST -08:00, _id: 4b416868010e2a04d0000002, views: 0, user_id: 4b416844010e2a04d0000001, description: "lorem?">]
>> Video.all
=> []
>> Picture.all
=> [#<Picture name: "Testing", _type: "Picture", created_at: Sun, 03 Jan 2010 20:02:48 PST -08:00, updated_at: Mon, 04 Jan 2010 13:01:31 PST -08:00, _id: 4b416868010e2a04d0000002, views: 0, user_id: 4b416844010e2a04d0000001, description: "lorem?">]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was pretty frustrating to say the least!